# How do I control which port is used for the Amber Smalltalk node.js server?

Tags: smalltalk, amber-smalltalk

Occasionally I need to run two node servers on two different Amber Smalltalk checkouts and it would be real convenient to be able to control this via the startup script, but my read of the startup script tells me that I'll have to edit some code, which is not ideal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[According to Johnny Thornton](https://twitter.com/#!/johnny_t/status/184078648335273984):

> in server/FileServer.st - after you have updated it there - I think
>   there is a Makefile in that same dir to help you recompile

So there's no way to do it (currently ~ Amber 0.9.3) without editing a file directlty.

Answer (score 5):

[Starting from today](https://github.com/amber-smalltalk/amber/pull/258) it is now possible in the Amber developer version to specify the port for the NodeJS based server.
This option is included in the 0.10.0 release of Amber.

The following line will start the server on port `12345`:

`node server/server.js -p 12345`

**EDIT:**

Both Amber REPL and Amber Server have been merged into a common tool called amber-cli.
Starting with Amber 0.11.0 the server can be started by executing the following command:

`node ./cli/js/amber-cli.js serve --port 12345 --host 0.0.0.0`